# mysql select on four tables Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select information from four tables of the database.

I need to have this:

`registos.data_registo, registos.hora_registo, registos.idSensor, registos.Temperatura, sensores.idLocalizacao, sensores_tem_alarmes.idAlarme, alarmes.descricao_alarme`

So I tried this:

```
select registos.data_registo, registos.hora_registo, registos.idSensor, registos.Temperatura, sensores.idLocalizacao, sensores_tem_alarmes.idAlarme, alarmes.descricao_alarme
 from registos, sensores, sensores_tem_alarmes, alarmes
   where registos.idSensor = sensores.idSensor 
   and sensores.idSensor = sensores_tem_alarmes.idSensor
   and sensores_tem_alarmes.idAlarme = alarmes.idAlarme
   group by sensores_tem_alarmes.idAlarme
   order by sensores_tem_alarmes.idAlarme desc;
```

Gives everything right, except the values ​​of the table records are not the correct values ​​appear.

Can anyone help me and tell where I'm failing? 
If someone does not understand the question let me try to explain better.

thank you

Model of database to help to understand

----edit----

In table Sensores isnt' idDescricao, is idLocalizacao

[image: Model of database to help to understand]

---------------------------------Edit--------------------------------

I try outer join, but give me the same result (Error)

```
select registos.data_registo, registos.hora_registo, registos.idSensor, registos.Temperatura, sensores.idLocalizacao, sensores_tem_alarmes.idAlarme, sensores_tem_alarmes.dataAlarme
from registos join sensores on registos.idSensor = sensores.idSensor
join sensores_tem_alarmes on sensores.idSensor = sensores_tem_alarmes.idSensor
group by sensores_tem_alarmes.idAlarme
order by sensores_tem_alarmes.dataAlarme desc;
```

Comment: You are joining all four tables...all tables should holds the record. If one table does not matches with the record..result will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for reply. what is supposed to do then?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used it. could you help me in a most practical way please?

Comment: you should give me a details like table wise, its be cant understand ..

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you want :(